# Object does not match target type with SetValue and enum

Tags: c#, dynamic, enums, propertyinfo

I tried adapting [this tutorial from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15292/Setting-Enum-s-Through-Reflection) to try and change a `dynamic` which will in this case be an int to a simple `Enum`.

If we define the `Enum` like so:

```
public Enum MyEnum { Zero = 0, One = 1, Two = 2 }
```

And the contents of a method to set the value of a `MyObject` class which contains an `MyEnum`:

```
var baseType = propertyInfo.PropertyType.BaseType; //`propertyInfo` is the `PropertyInfo` of `MyEnum`

var isEnum = baseType != null && baseType == typeof(Enum); //true in this case

dynamic d;

d = GetInt(); 

//For example, `d` now equals `0`

if (isEnum)
    d = Enum.ToObject(propertyInfo.PropertyType, (int)d); 

//I can see from debugger that `d` now equals `Zero`

propertyInfo.SetValue(myObject, d); 

//Exception: Object does not match target type
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Tip: let's declare a function with a parameter of type 'object' and try to call it with a 'dynamic' one. Put a breakpoint and check there what you will get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Object does not match target type" indicates that `myObject` is not an instance of the type that `propertyInfo` was obtained from.  In other words, the property you are trying to set is on one type, and `myObject` is not an instance of that type.

To illustrate:

```
var streamPosition = typeof(Stream).GetProperty("Position");

// "Object does not match target type," because the object we tried to
// set Position on is a String, not a Stream.
streamPosition.SetValue("foo", 42);
```

Comment: D'oh! I see the problem now! I was thinking the error message was talking about the property not the object. Thanks!